# Could somebody add low-poly and gameart related tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed there's no low-poly / high-poly / gameart tags but I don't have enough rep to add them. Could somebody please do that?

Comment: Can you point to at least 2 *existing* questions you think could benefit from this classification?

Comment: low-poly makes sense, the other two don't, the first is irrelevant and the second is better sub-classified.

Comment: 424 results for "[low poly](http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=low-poly)", 102 for "minecraft". [example 1](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58507/how-to-model-low-poly-nature-terrain), [example 2](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66180/how-to-get-that-triangulated-low-poly-look). I'm not an adept, but why not creating a "low-poly" tag ?